# Reading manifest: Error processing content_script: An unexpected property was found in the WebExtension manifest

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am trying to create a simple firefox addon that will modify page after XHR requests on pages. Unfortunately, after loading script, it shows error on about:debugging "Reading manifest: Error processing content_script: An unexpected property was found in the WebExtension manifest." It seems the content script then is not working at all.

Tried to change matches property to  and inside content_scripts but it didn't work

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "Some Name",
"version": "0.01a",
"applications": {
    "gecko": {
        "id": "some id"
    }
},
"description": "Some Description",
"author": "Some Author",
"icons": {
    "48": "icon.png",
    "96": "icon.png"
},
"background": {
    "scripts": ["jquery.min.js","declarations.js","bg.js"]
},
"content_script": [
    {
        "matches": ["*://somewebsite/folder/*"],
        "js": ["jquery.min.js", "content.js"]
    }
],
"permissions": [
    "storage",
    "*://somewebsite/folder/*",
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking"
]
}
```

What is wrong with the manifest.json? Where is error?

BTW, content.js:

```
console.log("CONTENT_SCRIPT");
function someFunction(request, sender, sendresponse) { somecode... }
browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(someFunction);
```

The first is console.log and it doesn't show CONTENT_SCRIPT neither on debugging console nor the web console.

bg.js:

```
browser.runtime.sendMessage({
        action: "timetodo",
        result: requestDetails
    });
```

Comment: After fixing the main issue, I have also found why sendMessage didn't work. Well, if you're using from background script to popup, you should use
`browser.tabs.sendMessage`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `"content_script"` key should be `"content_scripts"` (as it written in the  [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json)).

So use:

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "Some Name",
"version": "0.01a",
"applications": {
    "gecko": {
        "id": "some id"
    }
},
"description": "Some Description",
"author": "Some Author",
"icons": {
    "48": "icon.png",
    "96": "icon.png"
},
"background": {
    "scripts": ["jquery.min.js","declarations.js","bg.js"]
},
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["*://somewebsite/folder/*"],
        "js": ["jquery.min.js", "content.js"]
    }
],
"permissions": [
    "storage",
    "*://somewebsite/folder/*",
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking"
]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. It was very stupid question. I have checked one by one character and still didn't see while I knew it. It's so embarassing...

Comment: I just spent forever trying to fix a similar issue - I had used a dash and not an underscore